# What is the use of @relayhash value in graphql JS

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, github-graphql

I am performing code review on one of the source codes.

While going through a JS file (graphql.js) I found a value "@relayhash" along with some hash value as below:

@relayHash 00950038252b25a368700738a31fled7

I am not sure what this relay hash value is generally used for. Is it a threat from security perspective to display this public source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure how the hash is calculated exactly (I suspect some combination of the contents of the fragments in the component and the schema definitions) it does use this hash to determine if a warning should be displayed if the compiled Relay files (`.graphql.js`) are not up to date with the `schema.graphql`/`schema.json` definitions.

In summary, not a security risk, it is instead used to display a helpful warning message when developing an application using Relay when files are out of date.